# Problem with creating application for call recording with root permissions

Tags: java, android, call, voice

I am trying to make a call recording application on Xiaomi Redmi 4A with custome Havock system and Android 9.0 PIE. 
you can find the whole code here:

https://github.com/JakubBelka/CallRecording

I use MediaRecorder class to record voice during a phone conversation. In order to get very good quality recordings I want to set AudioSource as a VOICE_CALL instead of a microphone.

Code Below:

```
callrecorder = new MediaRecorder();
**callrecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);**
callrecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
callrecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
callrecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/record.amr");
try {
       callrecorder.prepare();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
callrecorder.start();
```

I have root permissions and this app is set as the default calling application, but I still have an error when I try to start recording:

```
System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
System.err:     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
System.err:     at RecordAnswer.doInBackground(RecordAnswer.java:24)
System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)  
System.err:     at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
System.err:     at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

I think the problem is in the selected audio source, because when I use DEFAULT source it's ok but the recording quality is not the best. I care about this because I want to record `VOICE_DOWNLINK` directly.

This is ok:

```
`callrecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        **callrecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);**
        callrecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        callrecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

Below are all my permissions from manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
```